How to use LLama3 as copilot hosting on other device?
I read about codegpt, it allows me to use every AI model in the same way as copilot is being used. I know I can use LLama3 there, but is there an option to place Llama3 on one device, and connect to that device with something like codegpt and ask questions? I want for multiple computers to use one model and I want to train that model

Yes, it's possible.
Fast and simple way

Download and launch desktop app LM Studio on the computer.
Enable LM Studio Server and Network discovery

Load desired model (like Llama3) into LM Studio.
Connect CodeGPT to LM Studio via plugin's "Custom OpenAI" provider.

I published detailed JetBrains IDE CodeGPT -> LM Studio step-by-step guidence here: https://github.com/carlrobertoh/CodeGPT/issues/384#issuecomment-2473137768
